# How to create a slide left effect in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to create a slide left effect to display my page after the loading bar.
I was trying to modify a piece of code I downloaded from a website.
I used the following line of code to display the division...

```
$("#wrapper").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

The code works fine in the tryit editor (http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_statements) but not in the browser.

Here is my demo page...

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39803954/loading/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included JQuery library in your page twice. On lines *7* and *12*. It causes an error.

Just remove those which is on the line *12*, since it is the older version (v1.3.1).

Comment: Thanks, That helped. I had the old library included for a slider, forgot to remove it.